# Python Tkinter Changing the Colour of a Cursor

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In my code I'm creating a gui that has various different buttons in it, and I have assigned cursors to each. What I'm wondering is how to change the colour of the cursor from the default white when hovered over these buttons.

```
B1 = Button(root, text='Delete Recording', bg = col1, cursor = "dotbox", width=15, command=killthat)
```

When hovered over, this turns the cursor into a dotbox.

I have tried adding colours like so

```
cursor = "dotbox brown1"
```

It doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't change the colour either.

Im running on Windows 7 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter supports cursor colors, but it could be that it's not supported on windows 7. I don't have a windows box to test on, but the following creates a green cursor on linux:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(cursor="dotbox green")
root.mainloop()
```

"brown1" may not be a valid color. At least on linux it's not. Have you tried an rgb value (eg: `cursor="dotbox #ff0000"`)?

Comment: Neither of these solutions seem to work. Perhaps cursor colours just completely aren't supported on Windows 7

Comment: @MemeMeister: colors don't work on OSX either. The code does work on linux, so this must be a limitation of Windows (or more specifically, a limitation of tkinter on Windows)